# 2-D plane division

Tags: c++, math, geometry, plane

Here is the problem statement:

*Chef is working with lines on a 2-D plane. He knows that every line on a plane can be clearly defined by three coefficients A, B and C: any point (x, y) lies on the line if and only if A * x + B * y + C = 0. Let's call a set of lines to be perfect if there does not exist a point that belongs to two or more distinct lines of the set. He has a set of lines on a plane and he wants to find out the size of the largest perfect subset of this set.

**Input**

The first line of input contains one integers T denoting the number of test cases. Each test case consists of one integer N denoting number of lines. Next N lines contain 3 space-separated integers each denoting coefficients A, B and C respectively.

**Output**

For each test case output the cardinality of the largest perfect subset in a single line. Constraints
Input:

```
1 5 
1 1 0 
1 2 3 
3 4 5 
30 40 0 
30 40 50
```

Output: 2 Explanation
Lines 3*x + 4*y + 5 = 0 and 30*x + 40*y + 0 = 0 form a biggest perfect subset.*

So if the ratios of As and Bs are the same, then the lines would be parallel which fulfills the problem statement. For example: if A[1] / B[1] == A[2] / B[2] then these line one and line two are parallel. But when the two lines in question are the same lines, which means there are an infinite number of common points, this equation holds, which is not what the problem wants. So we need to use C to determine whether the lines are the same or not (i.e. A[1]/A[2] == B[1]/B[2] == C[1]/C[2]). But the code I wrote with these ideas are so inefficient. Can you all suggest a more time-efficient solution?

Comment: "But the code I wrote..." Can you show us what you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a linear algorithm for this.

The idea is to have a map, where the key is a direction and the value is a set.
For each direction, the set contains only different lines which have the given direction. Then the answer is the size of the larger set.

The direction of a line `Ax + By + C = 0` is `A/B`. The problem is that if `B=0` it won't quite work as a key.
You can have a special set for the case `B=0`, which you keep separate and don't insert into the map.

The values that you insert into the set for a given line `Ax + By + C = 0`, should be `C/B`.
In the special case, when `B = 0`, you should use `C/A`.